# How can I update ad-b2c-react-native to the last version

Tags: react-native, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I´m relatively new in react-native and I have a problem that has been giving me a hard time the last few days. I have an app that uses azure ad-b2c authentication, for this I have been using the version 1.1.5 of ad-b2c-react-native. By following the documentation, I implemented three views using EditView, LoginView and EditView.

LoginView:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {Alert} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

import {LoginView, adService} from 'ad-b2c-react-native';;
import * as SecureStore from '../components/secure_store';
import Spinner from '../components/spinner';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart';

const ScreenLogin = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const connectivity = useSelector((state: any) => state.connectivity);

  const onSuccess = () => {
    navigation.reset({
      index: 0,
      routes: [{ 
        name: 'Profile',
        params: {
          afterLogin: true
        } 
      }],
    });
  };

  const onFail = (reason: string) => {
    Alert.alert(reason);
  };

  const check = () => {
    if(!connectivity || !(connectivity.output) || !(connectivity.output.isConnected)){
      RNRestart.Restart();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    check();
  }, [connectivity]);

  return (
    <LoginView
      appId="XXX"
      redirectURI="XXX"
      tenant="XXX"
      loginPolicy="XXX"
      onSuccess={onSuccess}
      onFail={onFail}
      secureStore={SecureStore}
      renderLoading={Spinner}
      scope="XXX"
    />
  );
};

export default ScreenLogin;
```

EditView:

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import React from 'react';
import {Alert} from 'react-native';
import {EditView} from 'ad-b2c-react-native';
import Spinner from '../components/spinner';

const ScreenEditProfile = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const onSuccess = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Success');
  };

  const onFail = (reason: string) => {
    Alert.alert(reason);
  };
  return (
    <EditView onSuccess={onSuccess} onFail={onFail} renderLoading={Spinner} />
  );
};

export default ScreenEditProfile;
```

LogoutView:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Alert} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {LogoutView} from 'ad-b2c-react-native';;
import Spinner from '../components/spinner';

import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart';

const ScreenLogout = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const onSuccess = () => {
    console.log('Logout OK');
    RNRestart.Restart();
  };

  const onFail = (reason: string) => {
    Alert.alert(reason);
  };

  return (
    <LogoutView
      redirectURI="XXX"
      onSuccess={onSuccess}
      onFail={onFail}
      renderLoading={Spinner}
    />
  );
};

export default ScreenLogout;
```

These views are added on the navigation stack to be used. The problem is that for some reason I had to migrate my app to a newer version of React-native and I had to update ad-b2c-react-native to the version 2.0.1. Now my app is no longer working because this library was completely re implemented. The thing is that this new version is not very well documented and I have not been able to translate my code from the previous version. The documentation has this example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";

import { AuthProvider } from 'ad-b2c-react-native';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

const prefix = Linking.createURL("/");

const linking = {
  prefixes: [prefix],
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
      <AuthProvider
            tenant= "<B2CAuthTenant>"
            appId="<B2CAppID>"
            loginPolicy="<B2CSignInPolicy>"
            passwordResetPolicy="<B2CPasswordResetPolicy>"
            profileEditPolicy="<B2CProfleEditPolicy>"
            redirectURI={Linking.createURL("redirect")} //redirect uri
            showInRecents = <Boolean>, // optional, default = false
            createNewTask = <Boolean>, //optional, default = false
          >
          <Routes/>
      </AuthProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I have not been able to find how can I create my three views and manage the navigation… Any help would be greatly appreciated.